# MessageBox.Show causes selected value to be reverted during ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I'm experiencing some weird behavior with the [`ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.90).aspx) event and am wondering if anyone has an explanation for it.

Somewhere in my event handler, I call [`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dac1663(v=vs.90).aspx).  If I choose a new value in my `ComboBox`, and my code causes the `MessageBox` to pop up, I am seeing my selceted value get reverted back to its original value.

When debugging, I am seeing that the selected value is correct before `MessageBox.Show`.  `MessageBox.Show` gives control back to the user until I click "Yes" or "No".  After I have clicked one of the options, control returns to the debugger and the value of my `ComboBox` is reverted back to its original value before my change.

I am not programmatically setting the selected value elsewhere, so I'm at a loss as to why the value gets reverted.  If the event handler does not pop the `MessageBox`, the selected does not get reverted.

Is it possible that the fact that I'm giving control back to the UI before I'm done handling the event has anything to do with it.  If so, is there a clean way to get around it?  Currently I'm capturing my selected value before I pop the `MessageBox` and then resetting it after, but I'd prefer to not have to resort to a "hack" to fix the issue.

Comment: To see some code would be nice

Comment: I could not recreate this so some code as duDE suggested would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was incorrect in my assumption that the subclass of `ComboBox` I was using did not add any relevant functionality.  The issue ended up being due to a `LostFocus` event handler I was unaware of that caused the `ComboBox` to revert its value.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely that the act of displaying the message box causes the combo box drop-down menu to close, thus abandoning any uncommitted selection the user may have made.

It's basically the same thing as dropping down a combo box, highlighting an item in the list, and then pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Notice that the highlighted item does not become the selected item because you never selected it before the combo box was dismissed. (You can try it easily yourself in the "Run" dialog.)

This is one of the many reasons why it's a bad idea to throw up message boxes all over the place (the other reasons include how visually jarring message boxes are to users, and that [most of them don't even bother to read them anyway](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html)). Programmers who like to use message boxes as debugging aids are often bitten by this exact scenario when they try to debug UI code.

The solution is to either:

1. Defer validation until the *entire form* is committed/submitted, at which time you can show a message box without running the risk of abandoning any currently dropped-down combo boxes.
2. Find an alternative (i.e., non-modal) way of displaying the validation error. WinForms provides an [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) control that you can use for this purpose. The typical usage is showing a little warning or error icon next to the control with the invalid value; the user can hover over that icon to display a tooltip with more information about the exact error.

Or perhaps a combination of both approaches, allowing the user to get instant feedback but also ensuring that you never have to handle malformed input outside of the input form.

Comment: As I understood it, the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event should only be fired when a change is actually committed to the `ComboBox`.  The name itself implies that the change is "committed".

Comment: @JonSenchyna It's probably some kind of race condition. Although upon actually tossing together a test project, it seems I can't reproduce the behavior. It does appear that the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event doesn't fire until after the selection has been committed. So I guess you're going to have to post repro code.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it using a slimmed-down test myself.  I think you're right about the race condition.  The repro code actually uses a subclass of `ComboBox` that, although it doesn't appear to change the functionality of the selection properties/events, may add enough extra weight to cause a race-condition.

Comment: It turns out my assumptions about out `ComboBox` class were wrong.  The issue is caused by a `LostFocus` event handler that is changing the value on me that I somehow missed in my initial digging.

Answer (score 0):

I could not recreate your issue using the code below which is essential what you are saying you are doing.  The value in the combobox gets updated. You may get a better solution by posting the SelectionChangeCommitted code.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
                string check1 = cb.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Messagebox check");
                string check2 = cb.Text;
                MessageBox.Show(check1 + "\n\n" + check2);
                //check 1 and 2 show the old value.  Once the method leaves then the value in the combobox is updated.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm looking at the value of cb.SelectedItem, rather than cb.SelectedItem.  I created a similar test case to yours and it gave me the new value both before and after the MessageBox call.

Comment: @JonSenchyna "cb.SelectedItem, rather than cb.SelectedItem"?

Comment: I can't edit my original comment anymore.  I meant to say that I'm looking at the value of `cb.SelectedItem`, rather than `cb.Text`.  `Text` is not updated until after the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is fired, but `SelectedItem` is updated before it.  That is why both values showed the original value in Sorceri's code.

Comment: which is why you should have supplied code, you are making people guess at what you are doing. Help us help you!